# Vue: Why is my dialog not showing up when the right condition is set?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, confirmation

EDIT: I answered my own question. I don't know how to mark this as resolved, since SO doesn't allow me to vote my own answer right now. Thanks everyone.

I am trying to create a confirmation box (asking to remove a layout) in which the user has to press `confirm` or `cancel` - `confirm` means 'yes, remove the layout and close the confirmation box', `cancel` means 'just close the box'.

The confirmation box opens when a user presses `RemoveButton` - this means that RemoveButton doesn't do the job of "removing" until `confirm` is pressed. Clicking the `RemoveButton` should make the dialog to show up.

The problem is the my dialog is not showing up. I ran Chrome dev tool and made sure that `setShowRemoveLayoutDialog(true)` is working, but `removeLayoutDialog` is not opening. Even when I set a dev tool breakpoint on `public removeLayout(layoutName: string)`, the dev tool could never reach it.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

(We don't have to talk about CSS here since it is already built by my other teammates)

(I cannot do `.confirm(confirm message)` because it will trigger a `no-alert` error for lint. So I have to insert it into `template` and make a div or element for that).

Thank you!

This is my Vue/html template:

```
<RemoveButton @press="setShowRemoveLayoutDialog(true)">
    <removeLayoutDialog v-if="showRemoveLayoutDialog"
      :layout-name="props.node.name"
      @confirm="removeLayout"
      @cancel="setShowRemoveLayoutDialog(false)"/>
</RemoveButton>
```

This is my `<script>`:

```
@Component({
    removeLayoutDialog,
    ...
})

export default class ThisClass {
    ...
    public showRemoveLayoutDialog = false;

    public removeLayout(layoutName: string) {
        this.doRemoveLayout(layoutName);
        this.showRemoveLayoutDialog = false;
    }

    public setShowRemoveLayoutDialog(isShown: boolean) {
        this.showRemoveLayoutDialog = isShown;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `@press` and not `@click`?

Comment: I think `@click` can only be done by a mouse. `@press` takes cares of the broader actions: the button can be pressed by whatever means I think?

Comment: I haven't heard about @press event at Vue and I am not able to google it now. But if you are sure it exists then ignore my comment. I certainly don't know everything.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that having the dialog inside the button was the problem. 
Instead of having `<button ... <dialog></dialog> </button>`, having `<button><dialog>` solved the problem.